# Check which network block devices are in use

Tags: linux, remote, block-device, nbd

How can I tell if a /dev/nbd* device is in use? Will "lsof" tell me? Or is there a better way? Is there an equivalent to "losetup -a" which will tell me the next free one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nbd-client -c /dev/nbdX` does not do the job correctly.

It may tell, that `/dev/nbdX` is not in use while it still is used internally in the kernel driver.  In that case you neither see this in `dmsetup` nor with `nbd-client`.

Example:

```
% nbd-client -c /dev/ndb2; echo $?
1
% e2fsck /dev/nbd2; echo $?
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
/dev/nbd2 is in use.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.
8
```

Actually the second indicator you need is revealed by `fsck`:

```
% strace e2fsck /dev/nbd2 2>&1 | grep open | grep /dev/nbd2
open("/dev/nbd2", O_RDONLY|O_EXCL) = -1 EBUSY (Device or resource busy)
```

Compare this with a really unused NBD-device:

```
% nbd-client -c /dev/ndb1; echo $?; strace e2fsck /dev/nbd1 2>&1 | grep open | grep /dev/nbd1
1
open("/dev/nbd1", O_RDONLY|O_EXCL) = 4
```

So this is the correct way to determine a `/dev/nbdX` is not used:

```
nbd-available()
{
nbd-client -c "$1";
[ 1 = $? ] &&
python -c 'import os,sys; os.open(sys.argv[1], os.O_EXCL)' "$1" 2>/dev/null;
}
get-available-nbd()
{
local a;
for a in /dev/nbd[0-9] /dev/nbd[1-9][0-9];
do
  nbd-available "$a" || continue;
  echo "$a";
  return;
done
return 1;
}
```

use it like `` nbd="`get-available-nbd`" || fail "no free NBD device" ``

Answer (score 3):

From the `man` page:

```
nbd-client -c /dev/nbdX
```